# Rest Framework Class Based Views with partial assignments

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm following the tutorial laid out [here](http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views.html) to create generic class based views for my API - however, I have run into a small problem. I would like to update the model behind the view partially. I used to be able to do this by using the `partial` property when I created the serializer. However, it seems that once I start using generic class based views I lose the ability to set whether or not I can allow partial updates to the model. How can I override the `partial` property of a ModelSerializer? My code is quite simple:

```
class DejavuUserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
  '''
    Get a user or update a user
  '''
  lookup_field = "email"
  queryset = DejavuUser.objects.all()
  serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = DejavuUser
    partial = True

  def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
    """
    Given a dictionary of deserialized field values, either update
    an existing model instance, or create a new model instance.
    """
    if instance is not None:
      #set the required fields and return the instance
```

I'm trying to access the API via PUT

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For partial updates use PATCH.

Also note that `partial` isn't an option on the serializer metaclass, but instead set on instantiating the serializer.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that worked. The assignment to partial there was just me desperately trying anything.